# How to update a Column from a Bunch of other columns

Tags: sql

I have a Table A where i column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4  and Column 5.

Column 1,2,3,4 already have data and we need to update Column 5 based on that data and on priority .

Column 1 has Priority 5 , Col 2 has Priority 4 ,Col 3 has priority 3 and  Col 4 has priority 2.

So if a particular row has all the column , then it should pick up Col 1 since it has highest priority  and update Col 5 ,
If a record has data only in Col 3 and 4 then it should be Col3 and update in Col 5 since 3 has higher priority than Col4 .
If there is no data from Col 1-4 , col 5 should be null.

I have 24k records in my Table and i need to run this for all rows.

Any pointers for this query would he highly appreciated .

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? what's your dbms?

Comment: Oracle . 
Col 1 Col2 Col3 COl4   Col5
1       2       3      4            1 (since Col1 has highest prioirty)
null    3     5      null         3( since Col2 is higher priority)
null    null  null  1             1(since only Col4  has data)
null   null   null  null        null( null since there is no data in any column)

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for an explanation on how to add sample data to a database question then **[edit]** your question. Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `coalesce()` -- assuming that the columns with no values have `NULL`:

```
update t
    set col5 = coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4);
```

You can also put the `coalesce()` in a `select`, if you don't want to actually change the data.

Comment: No i dont want values on Coalesce .
The data that should go in Col 5 should be based on reaming Columns .
So basically all other columns have a rating  associated with them .
So if a Col1 has highest rating , the data in COl 1should go in Col 5 also .

Comment: @Nirpeksh . . . That is what this does.